# DirectSound: "Value does not fall within the expected range." when initializing Notify

Tags: c#, directsound

I'm getting that exception when I try to run a simple DirectSound program. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound;

namespace AudioDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // output device

            var device = new Device();
            device.SetCooperativeLevel(GetDesktopWindow(), CooperativeLevel.Normal);

            // format description

            var format = new WaveFormat
            {
                BitsPerSample = 8,
                Channels = 1,
                FormatTag = WaveFormatTag.Pcm,
                SamplesPerSecond = 8000
            };

            format.BlockAlign = (short)(format.BitsPerSample / 8 * format.Channels);
            format.AverageBytesPerSecond = format.SamplesPerSecond * format.BlockAlign;

            var outputLatency = 20;
            var frameSize = format.AverageBytesPerSecond * outputLatency / 1000;

            // buffer 

            var description = new BufferDescription
            {
                BufferBytes = frameSize,
                Format = format,
                DeferLocation = true,
                GlobalFocus = true
            };

            var outputBuffer = new SecondaryBuffer(description, device);

            // buffer notifications

            var notify = new Notify(outputBuffer);

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I get the exception on the last line (`var notify = new Notify(outputBuffer);`).

Not sure what went wrong. The buffer was initialized correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do with your `outputLatency` and `frameSize` variables, or with the `BufferBytes` property, but my guess is there is where your problem is.

Comment: I want the buffer to hold 20ms of sound (= 320 bytes). that `*2` was just a test.

Comment: what C# framework would you use if you wanted to play sound data generated in real time?

Comment: The `waveOutOpen` API calls are still the best, IMHO (I use this for my own software synthesizer app). Here's a link to a good C# wrapper project: http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidA53BE0F5147E80A51FAC4A7CA140B80436D056EC.aspx

Comment: DirectSound is a gigantic pain in the butt to deal with, and support stopped for it a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

"*A SecondaryBuffer object will support notification events **only** if its `BufferDescription.ControlPositionNotify` is set to `true`.*"

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms812460.aspx)

So try this:

```
        var description = new BufferDescription
        {
            BufferBytes = frameSize,
            Format = format,
            DeferLocation = true,
            GlobalFocus = true,
            ControlPositionNotify = true
        };
```

I've had the same exception, but this solved the problem!